# NavigationDrawer + Google maps event

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a problem with pressing an option in my `navigationView` (`R.id.create_marker`) I want to create a marker in my `MapFragment`, but I can not do it, any suggestions?

**Code of `MainActivity.java` where I press the menu option:**

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new  NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.create_marker:
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Crear Marker",    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      // Create marker and display it on the map
      break;
    }
  return false;
}
});
```

**Code of `MapFragment.java`:**

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment
    implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private View rootView;
private GoogleMap gMap;
private MapView mapView;

public MapFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.map);
    if (mapView != null) {
        mapView.onCreate(null);
        mapView.onResume();
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
}
}
```

**This is the structure of my project:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To create a marker, you need to call `addMarker` method on your Map, once it's ready to be used.

```
 public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia,
        // and move the map's camera to the same location.
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.852, 151.211);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney)
                .title("Marker in Sydney"));
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
```

If you want your Map to open a marker for a fixed Lat-Lng, pass in the coordinates as shown in the code above, otherwise request location via Google Location Api and pass the obtained Lat-Lng values to the addMarker() method.